# Can someone clarify IOS Safari Service Worker Support

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, service-worker

Looking at the MDN documentation  IOS/Safari fully supports `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope.onfetch` but when you look at the `FetchEvent` specification it says it is not supported at all by Safari.

In particular, I would like to store some state for each client and was hoping to use the `fetchEvent.clientId` property of the event to index it.  Of course I presume I also have access to the `fetchEvent.request` object otherwise I can't see how a service worker can do anything useful and I could simulate clientID from a passed in parameter in the url.  But the docs don't really tell me what IOS/Safari supports and doesn't so I don't know which way to go.

Can someone please tell me precisely what does IOS/Safari pass when it calls the defined onfetch function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question by using https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/demos/fetchevent/

connecting my iPad to my Macbook and debugging my iPad.  I was eventually able to open the web inspector for the Service worker for that page, and the console.log showed the event passed in.

`FetchEvent.clientID` is present but a zero length string.  As it happens I did the same thing on my (linux) Desktop using Chrome and its also a zero length string, BUT it has another parameter `resultingClientId` with what looks like a UUID in it. That parameter is not there in Safari.

The `FetchEvent.request` is there, and in particular the URL.  So I can generate my own client id in the client (I am using `Date.now().toString()` as that is good enough for my purposes) for use in the service worker.  In fact my site without a service worker was using the in the URLs I need to intercept already, so I am happy that I have a solution.